# fadeIn / fadeOut based on a boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if I really have to write:

```
if (status) {
    $('#status-image-' + id).fadeIn();
} else {
    $('#status-image-' + id).fadeOut();
}
```

or there is a function to which I can provide my boolean status, something like:

```
$('#status-image-' + id).fade(status);
```

I've seen fadeToggle, but it doesn't accept a boolean status parameter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is not, but you can make one like that:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeInOrOut = function(status){
    return status ? this.fadeIn() : this.fadeOut();
}
```

and then call it like that (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xn7Up/1/) for a proof):

```
$('#status-image-' + id).fadeInOrOut(status);
```

Is it what you wanted?

Comment: nice one, thank you. do you know whether a jsfiddle remains forever or it will get deleted after sometime?

Comment: @stivlo: No problem. I do not know about any jsfiddle that has been deleted. You may ask jsfiddle's developers, whether it will stay forever, but they are very reliable, so I assume it will remain for a pretty long period of time.

Answer (score 6):

The shortest way I know of to write this, but one I find personally abhorrent, is this:

```
$('#status-image-' + id)[status ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']();
```

You can of course just add the proposed function straight to jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.fade = function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);  
        var status = args.shift();
        var func = status ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut';
        return $.fn[func].apply(this, args);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This is untested - I just knocked it up on the spot.

The first argument supplied will be your `status` parameter - the remaining arguments will be passed through to `.fadeIn()` or `.fadeOut()`.