# Show/hide text based on optgroup selection using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML markup:-

```
<select name="Fault" class="textbox" id="fault">
<option>Single Light Out</option>
<option>Light Dim</option>
<option>Light On In Daytime</option>
<option>Erratic Operating Times</option>
<option>Flashing/Flickering</option>
<option>Causing Tv/Radio Interference</option>
<option>Obscured By Hedge/Tree Branches</option>
<option>Bracket Arm Needs Realigning</option>
<option>Shade/Cover Missing</option>
<option>Column In Poor Condition</option>
<option>Several Lights Out (please state how many)</option>
<option>Column Leaning</option>
<option>Door Missing/Wires Exposed</option>
<option>Column Knocked Down/Traffic Accident</option>
<option>Lantern Or Bracket Broken Off/Hanging On Wires</option>
<option>Shade/Cover Hanging Open</option>
</select>

<span id="faulttext" style="color:Red; display:none">Text in the span</span>
```

This Jquery snippet adds the last 5 options into an option group.

```
$('#fault option:nth-child(n+12)').wrapAll('<optgroup  label="Urgent Reasons">');
```

What I want to do is, remove the `display:none` if any of the items within the `<optgroup>` are selected, effectively displaying the span message, possibly with a fade in transition, and also hide the message if any options outside of the `<optgroup>` are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$("#fault").change(function (event) {
    var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    $("#faulttext").toggle(!!$selected.closest("optgroup").length);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UPLUF/

Comment: how would i get a fade in/out effect on the text ??

Comment: @generalexception: Cool, was about to amend the answer `:)`

Comment: @generalexception: Although you may have to break it out into an `if...else`, it doesn't look like `fadeToggle` takes a boolean `showOrHide` like `toggle` does.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091537/fadein-fadeout-based-on-a-boolean seems to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fault').on('change', function(){
    if($('option:selected',this).is('optgroup > option',this))
        $('#faulttext').show();
});
```

You can work from here to achieve the inverse method.